# Value in the array of state variable is boolean true however when iterate each element of the state variable, the value is boolean false

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I use context to host global state variables that can be shared by components.

My context is like this:

```
const MyContext = React.createContext();

export const MyProvider = ({children}) => {

// declare the state variable in my context, students is an array of student object
const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider
      value={{
        students,
        setStudents,
      }}>
      {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

The above declared state hook host `students` variable & `setStudents` function. Each `student` object and the `students` array in practice like the following (Notice each student has a boolean field `graduated`):

```
[
{id: 123, name: 'John', graduated: false},
{id: 456, name: 'Bob', graduated: false},
...
]
```

(Yeah, of course I wrapped my app inside the context's provider. It's not the point for my question so I don't show it, but you know.)

So, now the `students` & `setStudents` are globally available to components and screens of my app.

Here is my screen to show students, when user tap on one student on the screen, that student is updated to `graduated: true`:

```
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import MyContext from '../context/MyContext';

const MyScreen = ()=> {
  // use context 
  const {students, setStudents} = useContext(MyContext);

  // I only need to run the code once to initialize my state variable so I wrap it inside the useEffect() hook like this
  useEffect(()=>{
    const initialStudents = parseBackendData();
    setStudents(initialStudents);
  }, []);

  // this function is called by the onPress of following layout component
  const onStudentPressed = (student) => {
    // the selected student is set to graduate: true & new array is returned
    const updatedStudents = updateStudentToGraduate(
      students,
      student,
    );
    // call the hook function
    setStudents(updatedStudents);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.main}>
        {students.map((student) => {
         
          return (
            <MyRow
              key={student.id}
              onPress={onStudentPressed}
            />
          );
        })}
      </View>
  )

}
```

When I run it, I tap on one student, MyScreen is re-rendered due to state change. Then I noticed the student I tapped has been updated to `graduate: true` when log it inside `useEffect` hook, but in the layout code when iterate `students.map(...)`, that student is still holding `graduated: false`. Why? How to have the layout render part using the correct state of students?

Comment: that's not how React works but if its occurs, create a state of students and try to manipulate all things with the local state and after that save into context

Comment: and can you please create codesandbox snippet for better understanding